# How to get crisp icons using Tabris

Tags: tabris

Currently the png images used in the application do not show up crisp and clear. There is clearly a resolution issue. We tried to change the resolution of the images like in page.setImage from 32x32 to even 128x128. The higher the resolution, the worse the images actually look.

In native iOS the resolution of the images used for retina displays are defined by a naming convention, like icon.png and icon@2x.png, which has double the resolution. 
Tried that as well, knowing there is no documented evidence that this should work.

Any words of wisdom?

Thanks!
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

This is planned for a future release. The API (based on SWT) does currently not support multiple images with different resolutions to be set on a single widget.